# SQL update site url and domain for wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Can you help me on my sql code?  It gives me a red line under under replace.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

Comment: all 'replace' and 'domain'.

Comment: seems to be odd to replace a string in a guid

Comment: guid includes also the domain and the page/product id

Comment: do you want to update all old URL to new URL in your database?

Comment: @AshPatel yes..

Comment: Try this software for replace URL from your database.and always use it whenever you want to replace URL from old to new one.https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Thank you @AshPatel I will try it. Do you any sql command of this?

Comment: this folder required no sql command , yu just upload it and go through page form URL...happy blogging..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put "Where" clause in your sql
You can try it

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com') where guid>0;

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') where ID>0;

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com')  where meta_id>0;
```

Comment: Still get same error. Do I need to update it online to become it works? I'm only doing this in my local server.